# Enable Copy&Paste in Entry

Tags: maui

I have some Entrys in my .NET MAUI App and tried to Copy & Paste some values to my Entry. The App is running in "**Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 API 33)**" started from VS.

When I try to paste and I click "Ctrl", I see the following arrow and when I click "Ctrl + V" nothing happens.

Is this a problem in the Emulator or do I have to enable Copy & Paste somehow in my App so that it is working?

Additional question regarding pasted values: when the Entry is Numeric and I try to paste a Text (e.g. "Abcd") will it then be rejected as expected? (But just to make it clear, I tried to paste numeric values)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v` can not be used in the Android emulator. These shortcut instructions are not suitable for the Android.

For Android, you can use the long press to select the words to copy then long press the entry to select the paste.

Comment: I am not an Android user. Is it like that on Android in general? So, I still stay by implementing the Gesture Recognizer for the TapGesture and see if the Clipboard hast Content and paste this?

Comment: Yes, this is the way to make the copy and paste on the android platform. Just like the operation on the Android physical device: making a copy then check it in the Clipboard or long press the entry then paste it.

Comment: In addition, if the android device support the keyboard it can use the ctrl+c and ctrl+v to enable Copy & Paste, but it not commonly used on phone form factor devices.